# What are the valid DepthBuffer Texture formats in DirectX 11? And which are also valid for a staging resource?

Tags: directx11, depth-buffer, sharpdx

I am trying to read the contents of the depth buffer into main memory so that my CPU side code can do Some Stuff™ with it.

I am attempting to do this by creating a staging resource which can be read by the CPU, which I will copy the contents of the depth buffer into before reading it. I keep encountering errors however, because of, I believe, incompatibilities between the resource format and the view formats.

[Threads](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/555411-dx10---depth-buffer-to-texture-problems/) like [these](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/direct3d/thread/a8d05f7f-ba07-4f7f-88c1-7ff6445df648) lead me to believe it is possible in DX11 to access the depth buffer as a resource, and that I can create a resource with a typeless format and have it interpreted in the view as another, but I cannot get it to work.

**What are the valid formats for the resource to be used as the depth buffer?** 
**Which of these are also valid for a CPU accessible staging resource?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The valid formats for typeless Direct3D11 depth buffer are:

```
DepthStencilBuffer: DXGI_FORMAT_R16_TYPELESS (instead of typical DXGI_FORMAT_D16_UNORM)
DepthStencilBufferView: DXGI_FORMAT_R16_FLOAT

DepthStencilBuffer: DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS (instead of typical DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT)
DepthStencilBufferView: DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT

DepthStencilBuffer: DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS (instead of typical DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT)
DepthStencilBufferView: DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS

DepthStencilBuffer: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G8X24_TYPELESS (instead of typical DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT)
DepthStencilBufferView: DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT_X8X24_TYPELESS
```

Using this format when declaring a depth stencil buffer, you should be able to copy the depth buffer to another R16_FLOAT/R32_FLOAT...etc. texture.

On a side note, it is often not recommended to read back data on the CPU because of the latency that will be introduced. Current techniques - on Windows Direct3D11 - tend to perform typical CPU computation on the GPU with DirectCompute.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed. I have created an R24G8_Typeless buffer with a D24_UNorm_S8_UInt DepthStencilView and a R24_UNorm_X8_Typeless staging resource.
I was not aware of DirectCompute but it looks like something I definitely want to know, thanks!